# Tags: excel vs ms-excel

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tag should be a synonym for [ms-excel](/questions/tagged/ms-excel). At the moment the [ms-excel](/questions/tagged/ms-excel) is pointing to [excel](/questions/tagged/excel).
The reason is that other Microsoft Office tags include "ms-", like [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) and [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word).

Probably this was already discussed, but I haven't found any comments, so am asking.

Comment: I think the reason is that `excel` was unambiguous, while tags named `word` and `access` could have different meanings.  (There was one large retagging around `access` a few years ago. People were using that tag for things like disk access and file access, so all `ms-access` questions were retagged.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, I understand, and agree. Also "word" can be a "two-byte value" etc. My opinion is that it could be uniform.